# How to set up a bridge interface, add eth0 to it, and have internet connection

Tags: network-interface, ip, bridge, headless, veth

I am trying to set up `br0` with `eth0` and `veth1` on a headless server where I am logged in via `ssh`.

I am doing this as a preparation to run a systemd service in a special namespace. This namespace will have the peer of the virtual divice as it's endpoint: `veth2`.

This should make it possible to set up static routes for just this process. In my case it will then route packages through a `vpn` while all the other traffic goes to the standard gateway.

To figure out how this works I wrote a small script that executes the following so fast that the `ssh` connection to the server does not break. I can then `traceroute` the `veth2` successfully. The server has just one `eth` device and no wifi which is why I have to do it this way.

My problem is that after executing the script the server does not have internet access any more. I am probably missing a lot here. Can anyone help?

My script:

```
pi@testpi:~ $ cat add_bridge_and_veth1.sh 
brctl addbr br0;
ip addr del 192.168.100.222/24 dev eth0;
ip addr add 192.168.100.222/24 dev br0;
brctl addif br0 eth0;
ip link set dev br0 up;
ip link add name veth1 type veth peer name veth2;
brctl addif br0 veth1;
brctl show;
ip netns add nsben1;
ip link set veth2 netns nsben1;
ip netns exec nsben1 ip addr add 192.168.55.101/24 dev veth2;
ip netns exec nsben1 ip link set lo up;
ip netns exec nsben1 ip link set veth2 up;
```

No internet after this in the default namespace:

```
pi@testpi:~ $ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.100.222 (192.168.100.222)  3085.668 ms !H  3085.488 ms !H  3085.393 ms !H
pi@testpi:~ $ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.100.222 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

EDIT: My default setup is very simple. `eth0` gets a fixed IP in `192.168.100.0/24` from the router according to the `MAC` of the device: `192.168.100.222`.

```
pi@testpi:~ $ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:98:70:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.222/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 83282sec preferred_lft 72482sec
    inet6 fe80::247e:fd3c:36d7:68f5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:98:70:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.222/24 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe98:704b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: veth1@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e2:bc:58:01:67:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns nsben1
    inet 169.254.205.121/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute veth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::db71:b4e9:c60f:5865/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

No network in `nsben1`, but this is not my main concern yet. I first want to have everything working in default namespace.

```
root@testpi:~# ip netns exec nsben1 ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Here the output for `ip route` in default and `nsben1` namespaces. I think `Network is unreachable` from the `nsben1` results from the internet beeing unreachable from default namespace. It does not necessarily mean that something is wrong with the `nsben1`, but even if that's not the main problem at the moment.

```
root@testpi:~# ip route
192.168.55.0/24 dev veth2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.55.101 
root@testpi:~# ip route get 8.8.8.8
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
root@testpi:~# ip netns exec nsben1 ip route
192.168.55.0/24 dev veth2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.55.101 
root@testpi:~# ip netns exec nsben1 ip route get 8.8.8.8
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

For the sake of completeness `ip a` in `nsben1`:

```
root@testpi:~# ip netns exec nsben1 ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: veth2@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:31:7e:0f:89:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.55.101/24 scope global veth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9031:7eff:fe0f:899d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

**I tried @berndbausch's approach** of just executing the first five commands

```
brctl addbr br0;
ip addr del 192.168.100.222/24 dev eth0;
ip addr add 192.168.100.222/24 dev br0;
brctl addif br0 eth0;
ip link set dev br0 up;
```

in a script. When I do this I get the following output, where `br0` and `eth0` still have the same IP, which probably is wrong:

```
pi@testpi:~ $ sudo ./add_bridge.sh
pi@testpi:~ $ ip route
192.168.100.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.222 
pi@testpi:~ $ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:98:70:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.222/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 86389sec preferred_lft 75589sec
    inet6 fe80::247e:fd3c:36d7:68f5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:98:70:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.222/24 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe98:704b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I then tried to execute the script adding `ip link set dev eth0 down;` and `up` like this:

```
ip link set dev eth0 down;
brctl addif br0 eth0;
ip link set dev eth up;
```

I lose the connection via `ssh` which is understandable. Maybe it is normal that `eth0` has the same IP as the `br0` it is connected to. If not, why is the IP not removed despite me using `ip addr del 192.168.100.222/24 dev eth0;`

Comment: To reduce the number of moving parts, I suggest you first try a shorter script that just adds `eth0` to the bridge, i.e. the first five commands. They should be OK I think, except that you might have to bring `eth0` down (?) before adding it to the bridge. Also, I'd like to see the bridge config after the script, and the output of `ip a`. Once you get this first step to work, add the rest one babystep after the other. I can't comment if your desired config makes sense.

Comment: As dirkt says, somehow the default route got lost in the process. In fact, there isn't even a route to 192.168.100.0/24, the subnet to which eth0 is connected. How did this happen? And why does the default bamespace have a route via veth2, which exists only in nsben1?

Comment: When you assign an IP address to an interface, automatically a route via that interface is added to the routing table. It is strange that this doesn't happen for br0, but you could add the route explicitly in the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Consider using a `macvlan` from the network namespace instead of a veth-pair and a bridge. The effect is the same, but it's simpler to set up, and more efficient.
2. Having both `192.168.100.*/24` and a `192.168.55.*/24` on the same bridge looks very wrong. You didn't tell us anything about your general network setup, but the segment where you connect everything should have a **single** IP range. Or use a VLAN, if you want different segments on the same physical wire.
3. I don't really remember if you can do the manipulations you did above without the interfaces being down or forced down, so also set `veth1` and `eth0` to `up` in a final step. My guess is that this is what is causing the trouble.
4. You didn't mention if the "no internet" happens in the main network namespace, in `nsben1`, or in both. Please edit your question and add this information.
5. Also check routing; without knowing the rest of your networking setup I have no idea what the default route was, and if it's still correct. Check with `ip route` and `ip route get 8.8.8.8` in both namespaces.

---

For macvlan, you create a new macvlan, set `eth0` as master to it, leave `eth0` in the main network namespace, and move the new macvlan to the new namespace. In the new namespace, you can use DHCP or whatever to obtain an IP address, and you also need to setup the default route again (because routing is per namespace).

Comment: The `veth2` inside the namespace will appear to be on the same segment. In particular, `veth2` with `.55.` and `br0` with `.100.` should be able to ping each other (and everything else on the LAN), which just doesn't work with those ranges. You are *deleting* the IP from `eth0` and moving the exact same IP addr to `br0`, which is exactly how it should be. Direct bridge members like `eth0` can no longer carry an IP address. If all interfaces are up, debug by fixing the address ranges, and try to ping `br0` from `veth2`, and vice versa. Then ping the gateway in your LAN, whatever that is.

Comment: And you don't have a default route, so `8.8.8.8` won't work before you add it.

Comment: If it reappears again, you have something else running in the background (network manager?) which can potentially interfere with what you are trying to set up. And yes, you can also get the address with DHCP, which in your setup should be for `br0`. And no, bridge members don't get an IP address - bridging is OSI layer 2, not layer 3.

Comment: I stopped `dhcpcd.service` and now `eth0` stays without IP after `addr del`! But with doing it the two routes related to it are gone, too. I guess I just have to add them manually now with `br0` instead of `eth0`.

Comment: `sudo ip route add default via 192.168.100.1 dev br0` and now I can `ping 8.8.8.8`. Not sure if stopping `dhcpcd.service` will have any problematic side effects. I should probably configure it for `br0` instead...

Comment: This is now turning into remote debugging, and the Q&A format isn't really suited for that. Please have again a look at (1) in the answer, using a macvlan inside the namespace will avoid any complications you have with the existing setup for `eth0`.